# insert a scaled picture on the right side of the page on an existing picture in latex

Tags: graphics, horizontal-alignment, scaling

I am new user of latex. Can I insert a scaled image on the right side of the page?While, I have already full size image on the same page. There is no text on this page. Thanks in advance.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Fast Fourier Transform}
    \frametitle{Fast Fourier Transform}
    \scriptsize
    \begin{figure}[!h]
        \centering
        \begin{flushright}
            \includegraphics[scale=0.15]{images/fft.pdf}
            \end{flushright}
        \includegraphics[scale=0.555]{images/fft4.pdf}
        \caption{Signal Processing  Blocks}

    \end{figure}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: \documentclass[]{beamer}

Comment: \subsection{Fast Fourier Transform }
 \begin{frame}{Fast Fourier Transform}
  \frametitle{Fast Fourier Transform}
  \scriptsize
  \begin{figure}[!h]
   \centering
   \begin{flushright}
    \includegraphics[scale=0.15]{images/img1.pdf}
    \end{flushright}
   \includegraphics[scale=0.555]{images/img2.pdf}
   \caption{Signal Processing  Blocks}
   
  \end{figure}
 \end{frame}

Comment: Please edit your post. Don't put the code in the comments. Also read here: http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436

Comment: Do you want the scaled picture overlaid atop the full-size picture or adjacent to the full-size picture?  If the latter, do you want the scaled picture within the margin or outside the margin?

Comment: Actually I want to overlaid the flushright image on the full scaled image. I mean, first  image that is full scaled according to page but it has some white place on the right side corner, where I want to insert second image. any idea ? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is another way, with `\stackinset`.  In this MWE, I inset it 10pt from the right-top of the main image.  Those values can be changed in the argument list, even including negative offsets.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Title}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\stackinset{r}{10pt}{t}{10pt}{\includegraphics[width=.15\linewidth]{example-image-B}}
{\includegraphics[width=.8\linewidth]{example-image-A}}
\caption{This is my caption}
\end{figure}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You may be interested in the following setup:

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{My title}

  \centering
  \adjustbox{valign=T}{\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}c@{}}
    \includegraphics[width=.7\linewidth]{example-image-a} \\
    Some caption
  \end{tabular}}%
  \adjustbox{valign=T,llap}{\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}c@{}}
    \includegraphics[scale=0.1]{example-image-b}
  \end{tabular}}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Since floats (like `figure`) are not really used in ([`beamer`](http://ctan.org/pkg/beamer)) presentations, setting it inside a `tabular` would be just-as-good.

Placement of the overlaid image (vertical alignment or otherwise) can be adjusted.